# XML layout design for android device having different screen size & density

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I want to have the same UI in all the android device, just like I'm re-sizing a 
screen shot.

Currently, I have developed XML layout with reference of 320x480 or 360x640 and measure size as per this mdpi resolution & assign size in DP to XML element.

can anyone suggest me how to improve the design, is it possible to have pixel perfect design in each and every phone?

**Actual Result of Screen:**

[image]

**Expected Result of Screen:**

[image]

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34996396/2826147) on SO

Comment: @Amit app is only for mobile, still to improve UI on bigger device we have create layout in 2 resolution (layout-hdpi & layout-xxhdpi) but still we are facing issue in some  devices link samsung s6 edge+.